# Appium : ript threw an uncaught JavaScript error: Error getting next command, shutting down

Tags: ios7.1, appium

Team,

I am getting the below error when I try to launch the console with Appium 1.2.2 version.

Device: iOS 7.1.2

ERROR:

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 15:12:32 +0000 Error: Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: Error getting next command, shutting down :-( on line 196 of commands.js

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 15:12:32 +0000 Stopped: Script was stopped by the user

Appium version : 1.2.2

Full logs:

```
error: iOS log capture failed: spawn ENOENT

info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir:
info: [debug] Dynamic env:
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code:
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path:
info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap:
info: [debug] Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Starting iOS device log capture via deviceconsole
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
info: [debug] Error: spawn ENOENT
at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: spawn ENOENT)","code":"ENOENT","errno":"ENOENT","syscall":"spawn","origValue":"spawn ENOENT"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 272.799 ms - 197 
info: [debug] Not setting device type since we're connected to a device
info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0
info: [debug] Couldn't find ideviceinstaller, trying built-in at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstaller
info: [debug] Checking app install status using: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap isInstalled --id 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0 --bundle com.sg.application.TestApp2

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: spawn ENOENT

info: [debug] App is installed.

info: [debug] fullReset not requested. No need to install.
info: [debug] Starting command proxy.

info: [debug] Instruments socket server started at /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Starting instruments
info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
info: Launching instruments
info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0 com.sg.application.TestApp2 -e UIASCRIPT /Users/rsangili/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-3fd3829137e4c5d0.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2014-09-23 10:11:48.859 instruments[1619:507] Connection to the remote device lost while launching target. Aborting...

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Error Starting Recording

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253

info: [debug] Killall instruments

info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #1
info: [debug] Killall iPhoneSimulator

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code null

info: [debug] Cleaning up after instruments exit
info: [debug] Instruments exited unexpectedly
warn: Setting initial orientation did not work!
info: [debug] Shutting down command proxy and ignoring any errors
info: [debug] Closing socket server.
info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Instruments socket server was closed

error: Unhandled error: TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Server. (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/lib/command-proxy.js:198:9)
at Server.g (events.js:180:16)
at Server.emit (events.js:117:20)
at net.js:1276:10
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13) context: [POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"7.1","newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium","deviceName":"iPhone Retina (4-inch)"}}]

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code null
info: [debug] Cleaning up after instruments exit
info: [debug] Instruments exited unexpectedly
info: [debug] Shutting down command proxy and ignoring any errors
info: [debug] Destroying instruments client socket.
info: [debug] Closing socket server.
info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Instruments socket server was closed
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons

error: Unhandled error: TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Server. (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/lib/command-proxy.js:198:9)
at Server.g (events.js:180:16)
at Server.emit (events.js:117:20)
at net.js:1276:10
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13) context: [POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"7.1","newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium","deviceName":"iPhone Retina (4-inch)"}}]

info: [debug] Cleaning app state.

info: [debug] Cleaning app state.

info: [debug] Deleted /Users/rsangili/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications

info: [debug] Deleted /Users/rsangili/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Library/TCC

info: [debug] Deleted /Users/rsangili/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Library/Caches/locationd

info: [debug] Deleted /Users/rsangili/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Media
info: [debug] Deleted /Users/rsangili/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Library/Keychains
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
info: [debug] Deleted /Users/rsangili/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session

info: Launching instruments

info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0

info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0 com.sg.application.TestApp2 -e UIASCRIPT /Users/rsangili/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-3fd3829137e4c5d0.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.619 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 28.591 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 15:12:03 +0000 Error: Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: Error getting next command, shutting down :-( on line 196 of commands.js

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 15:12:03 +0000 Stopped: Script was stopped by the user

info: [debug] [INST] Instruments Trace Complete (Duration : 8.119442s; Output : /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace)

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 0

info: [debug] Killall instruments

info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #2
info: [debug] Killall iPhoneSimulator

info: Launching instruments

info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0

info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0 com.sg.application.TestApp2 -e UIASCRIPT /Users/rsangili/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-3fd3829137e4c5d0.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 15:12:18 +0000 Error: Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: Error getting next command, shutting down :-( on line 196 of commands.js

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 15:12:18 +0000 Stopped: Script was stopped by the user

info: [debug] [INST] Instruments Trace Complete (Duration : 8.202824s; Output : /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace)

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 0

info: [debug] Killall instruments

info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #3
info: [debug] Killall iPhoneSimulator

info: Launching instruments

info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0

info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 0058679bc8d12f8a56243d8de88b0d7e14dc09c0 com.sg.application.TestApp2 -e UIASCRIPT /Users/rsangili/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-3fd3829137e4c5d0.js -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 15:12:32 +0000 Error: Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: Error getting next command, shutting down :-( on line 196 of commands.js

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-09-23 15:12:32 +0000 Stopped: Script was stopped by the user

info: [debug] [INST] Instruments Trace Complete (Duration : 6.118680s; Output : /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace)

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 0

info: [debug] Killall instruments

info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] We exceeded the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start; failing launch
info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons

info: [debug] Cleaning app state.

info: [debug] No folders found to remove

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.403 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.452 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.671 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.155 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.371 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.211 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.945 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.655 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.969 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.842 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.964 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.665 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.047 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.824 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.942 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.767 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.876 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.516 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.924 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.146 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.921 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.780 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.846 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.751 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.887 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.809 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.100 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.009 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.2.2","revision":"cf6ff5939ddc6b4d45fcbabfbfe13c950e0058c4"}}}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: Please provide your DesiredCapabilities for more assistance. Try going through the questions in my answer and see if one of those things seems to be the problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same JS complaint with appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-dea1a1242b3bfb9b.js on line 2965 using the iOS Simulator with iPhone 5 + 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

## Debugging Real Device automation for iOS

These are the things you should check for to debug your Real Device automation problems.

1. Is the device "Setup for Development" in Xcode?
2. Is the device unlocked?
3. Are you giving it an `.ipa` to install?

   - Make sure the `.ipa` is signed with a Development certificate
   - `.app` or `.xcarchive` files will not work on real devices.
4. Are you giving it the bundle id of an already installed application?

   - Was that app deployed to the device for Development or Distribution?
   - Appium cannot automate apps installed via:

     - the App Store
     - An MDM solution (unless the TestFlight app is signed with a `Development` certificate)

Comment: 1) YES 2) YES 3) YES (IPA file signed with developer profile) 4) NO. 4a) Development

Comment: You need to unlock the device before starting Appium. If you need to unlock it via a passcode, Instruments won't start

Comment: This is one of many reasons why Real Device automation for iOS is not recommended

Comment: The device is unlocked. Why still I see the issue?

Comment: Paste your client-side code in your question and I'll see what else might be going on

Comment: I am using appium.app. Please refer this case for more detailshttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003675/appium-not-able-to-launch-the-inspector

Comment: Uncheck "app"! If you set bundleid, it will use the bundleid to find the .ipa that is on your device.

Comment: Try removing platformVersion from your capabilities! I had this issue hanging for a week, the app compiled for iOS 7.1 crashed instruments on the start. After removing this cap the simulator ran fine!